# Using custom filters (server side) for OpenLayers Vector Layer

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, layers, filter

I have a vector layer in openlayers with source in GEOJSON (custom php server, which I have in complete control) and BBOX strategy.

Vector points contain point sources which have different attributes. I want to implement some filters by one or two attributes. I can manage server side php code - for e.g. I can get the filters by adding URL parameters to existing url like:

```
Existing URL: mywebservice.php
Filtered URL: mywebservice.php?someattributte=somevalue
```

How do I implement it on the OpenLayers side?

My code is as follows:

```
            var in_options = {
                'internalProjection': EPSG_900913,
                'externalProjection': EPSG_4326
            };
            var ems_sources = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(EMS_SOURCES_TITLE, {
                strategies: [
                             new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({
                                 resFactor: 2,
                                 active: true,
                                 autoActivate: true,
                                 ratio: 1.3
                             })

                         ],
                 protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                     url: EMS_SOURCES_WS,
                     callbackKey: 'callback',
                     format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(in_options)
                 })
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question based on retrieved answers just to make it clearer.

```
           //Declare a variable layer ems_sources
           var in_options = {
                'internalProjection': EPSG_900913,
                'externalProjection': EPSG_4326
            };
            var ems_sources = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(EMS_SOURCES_TITLE, {
                strategies: [
                             new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({
                                 resFactor: 2,
                                 active: true,
                                 autoActivate: true,
                                 ratio: 1.3
                             })

                         ],
                 protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                     url: "myWebServiceURL.php",
                     callbackKey: 'callback',
                     format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(in_options),
                     params: {filter: ""} //initial filter is set to empty string
                 })
            });


            //add layer to the map
            map.addLayer(ems_sources);



           //call this function in order to refresh data and apply filter
           function refreshData(filter) {
                 ems_sources.protocol.params.filter= "myAttributeValue";
           }
```

By calling refreshData function and providing filter attribute the URL for sources retrieval will look like this:

myWebServiceURL.php?filter=myAttributeValue

I should just apply the server side web service to filter the results according to the filter parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass params object in the `OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP`. See here http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Protocol/HTTP-js.html#OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP.params

your protocol part of code should look like

```
protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                 url: EMS_SOURCES_WS,
                 callbackKey: 'callback',
                 format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(in_options),
                 params: {someattributte:somevalue}
             })
```